# NSIS message box localization guidance

Tags: localization, nsis

I am writing NSIS scripts for our application. Everything is just great except message box localization: the problem is text in message boxes is already localized, whereas `OK`, `CANCEL` and other buttons is not.

I checked language files, definitions are correct, I also load required language files, before `.onInit` and use `LangDLL` to input installation language from user. I have searched NSIS wiki and help files, but could not find anything regarding this problem.

Could you please guide me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you do not need to write totally new plug-in - you may use **nsWindows** plug-in (http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=304431&highlight=nswindows) which is suitable for creating new windows in NSIS.

Create replacement for MessageBox - new window with label, icon, caption and appropriate methods for this window.

It is a lot of work but it is only way and such window will be Windows (language) independent (as Anders said).
Also  then setting font style/size/width will be possible as many other customizations.

Answer (score 0):

NSIS uses the [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function so the buttons will use the same language as Windows. The only way around this would be to write a custom NSIS plugin...